# AOSP Sony Build Error

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, sony-xperia

I've been trying to compile AOSP for Xperia Z3+/Z4 D6533 (kitakami-ivy, ivy-dsds). After deleting sony-oss and moving toolbox to the out/target/.../utilities/toybox, I finally got the build to compile. That is, until this:

> [ 28% 14657/50913] build out/target/product/ivy/root/init.real
>
> FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(cp out/target/product/ivy/utilities/tooybox out/target/product/ivy/root/sbin/toybox_init) && (cp out/target/product/ivy/utilities/keycheck out/target/product/ivy/root/sbin/keycheck) && (cp out/target/product/ivy/utilities/init_sony out/target/product/ivy/root/sbin/init_sony) && (if [ ! -L out/target/product//ivy/root/init ]; the        echo \"/init out/target/product/ivy/root/init isn't a symlink\";       mv out/target/product/ivy/root/init out/target/product/ivy/root/init.real;        ln -s sbin/init_sony/target/product/ivy/root/init;          else        echo \"/init out/target/product/ivy/root/init is already a symlink\"; fi )"

After that, Jack starts and build/core/ninja.mk:148 stops build with error 1. I'm out of ideas as this issue has never been seen on the web before. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Extra details in case it's necessary:
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Gnome instead of Unity), kernel 4.4.0.57
OpenJDK 8 Update 111

Comment: What is the error message from this command? That should give you a hint what's wrong. The error message might be above this line.

Comment: I don't understand what it's saying though. It won't copy a bunch of files, and at the same time it did not echo the symlink message. So what is wrong here?

Comment: Run "make" with one thread only, then you'll see the error message more close to the fail message. If the copy command fails, there must be an error message e.g. "file not found" or "permission denied" etc.

Comment: cp: omitting directory 'out/target/product/ivy/utilities/toybox'

Comment: In the first cp, it says "tooybox" and not "toybox". Why?

Comment: I typed it out on my laptop instead of copy-paste since my desktop was running something at the time. x)

Comment: As you may know, the cp command without parameter "-r" only copies regular files, not directories. "Omitting directory" means exactly that. Just an idea. Good luck!

Comment: Sony fixed it in a patch. I guess they fixed the cp -r issue then. Thanks for your help! :)